# GPU Dask Cuda cluster: client.submit

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, cupy

I am quite familiar with Dask distributed for CPUs. I'd like to explore a transition to running my code on GPU cores. When I submit a task to the LocalCUDACluster I get this error:

```
ValueError: tuple is not allowed for map key
```

This is my test case:

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client

cluster = LocalCUDACluster()
c = Client(cluster)

def test_function(x):
    return(x+1)

sample_np = np.array([0,1])
sample_cp = cp.asarray(sample_np)

test_1 = test_function(sample_cp)
test_2 = c.submit(test_function,sample_cp)
test_2 = test_2.result()
```

test_1 output:

```
array([1, 2])
```

test_2 output:

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize
.....
ValueError: tuple is not allowed for map key
```

How do I correctly distribute tasks on CUDA cores?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get it working by first installing the Dask Distributed and Dask CUDA release.

However, I noticed that only 1 worker is available, but I have 600 CUDA cores. How do I distributed individual tasks on these 600 CUDA cores? I'd like to parallelize tasks on these 600 cores.

Versions:

```
dask 2.17.2
dask-cuda 0.13.0
cupy 7.5.0
cudf 0.13.0
msgpack-python 1.0.0
```

Comment: Dask briefly experienced some issues while upgrading to `msgpack` 1.0 a few months back. This should work in a current Dask/Distributed/Dask-CUDA release. What versions of those libraries (and msgpack) are you using?

Comment: It seems that Dask is serially executing tasks on the GPU cluster, this is not my intention. Any ideas why?

Comment: Dask's distributed scheduler is single threaded (CPU and GPU), and Dask-CUDA uses a one worker per GPU model. This means that each task assigned to a given GPU will run serially, but that the task itself will use the GPU for parallelized computation. You may want to look at the Dask documentation and explore Dask.Array (which also supports GPU arrays).

Comment: If you only have one GPU and are not memory bound, you may want to simply use CuPy rather than Dask + CuPy.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I expected to be able to distributed tasks in parallel on GPU cores, as I do on CPU cores/processes, but I understand this is not (yet) possible. I guess my workload is not appropriate for GPUs.

Comment: To clarify, your task *is* distributed in parallel on GPU cores, just not at the scheduler level. To make this concrete, with an array of `np.random.normal(5,5, (10000,1000))`, I get the following `%timeit` results: `%timeit sample_np + 1 # 21.7 ms ± 86.4 µs per loop` and `%timeit sample_cp + 1; cuda.synchronize() # 216 µs ± 695 ns per loop`. (I need to synchronize to fairly compare, since CuPy is async). Note how much faster the GPU operations are. The GPU (used like this) won't provide a benefit if your data is very small, though.

Comment: If you need more fine-grained control over parallelism but don't want to write CUDA code, you should look at Numba.cuda. It's quite powerful and may be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm indeed looking for fine-grained control, will take a look.

Comment: Just to add to Nick's comments, a GPU works very differently from a CPU, given the amount of cores a GPU has the resources per core (registers, cache) are more limited than a CPU. Unlike CPU code, CUDA kernels are inherently parallel, that is the level where parallelization will occur in a single GPU. Dask/Dask-CUDA will allow you to parallelize over multiple GPUs without writing code specifically targeting multiple GPUs, as it does to single-threaded CPU code to target multiple threads/cores. Long story short: use Dask-CUDA for multi-GPU, and libraries such as CuPy and Numba for single GPU.

Comment: In case you're interested in more details about how a GPU works, I would suggest reading [An Even Easier Introduction to CUDA](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).

Comment: Thanks for answering folks.  If you are willing next time it'd be great if you can provide an actual answer in the StackOverflow UI.  That serves as a signal for other answerers  that this question has been answered and that they can skip it, which saves everyone time.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this question has an answer in the comments.  I'm going to copy a response from Nick Becker

Dask's distributed scheduler is single threaded (CPU and GPU), and Dask-CUDA uses a one worker per GPU model. This means that each task assigned to a given GPU will run serially, but that the task itself will use the GPU for parallelized computation. You may want to look at the Dask documentation and explore Dask.Array (which also supports GPU arrays).